# iTunes podcast reader won't work with MP3 files pushed through PHP

Tags: php, xml, itunes

I use a simple php script that redirect to an MP3 file after doing some statistic collection work that I put in my podcasts RSS.

It's in the form of http://domain.com/downloads.com?url=http://domain.com/podcast.mp3

While it works pretty much everywhere I tested it (castfeedvalidator.com and some podcast readers), it seems that iTunes just won't work with it. I add the feel, the title appears but it's like there is absolutely no episode to the feed.

Anyone have any experience like this and solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel ashamed, but I totally never saw the answer to my own questions while reading [Apple's documentation on podcasting](https://www.apple.com/ca/itunes/podcasts/specs.html).

> The URL preceding GET-style form values (before the first “?”) must end in a media file extension (such as .mp3).
>
> Correct
>   http://www.podcaster.com/load.mp3?f=&Wipeout.mp3
>
> Incorrect
>   http://www.podcaster.com/load.php?f=&Wipeout.php